# How can I disable these tooltips?

Tags: go, emacs

I've recently installed gopls and I am using it through Emacs (lsp-mode). Everything works fine but I would like to disable these tooltips (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRiGI.png).

I tried setting `setq lsp-go-hover-kind "NoDocumentation"` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest lsp-ui update fixes this.